# How can I add a fade out effect to the active tab-pane?

Tags: javascript, tabs, bootstrap-5, fade

I'm using basic Bootstrap 5.3 with the basic pills and tab structure. How can I simply add a fadeOut to the active tab before the fadeIn of the selected tab?

It seems like adding the "fade" class only adds a fadeIn, I want the active tab to slowly disappear before.

The only way I have found so far is to override the whole mechanism and do a jQuery fadeout fadein. I wish I could use more standard code...

Can some please help?

Thanks!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-disabled-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-disabled" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-disabled" aria-selected="false" disabled>Disabled</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-disabled" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-disabled-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @FiddlingAway: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It delays the display of the new tab, but the "active" tab still disappears right away. I think the active tab doesn't fade at all, it's directly hidden. I've tried to catch the 'hide.bs.tab' event, in that case I can successfully fade out the active tab, but then I need to "preventDefault()" and can't successfully go back on the "normal" behavior of bootstrap tab.

Comment: @isherwood: Thanks, but using the "fade" attribute makes an animation anyway. The only thing I find not "beautiful" is that the tab disappear right away, then another fades in. I wish it would be "fade out fade in", but basically i'm not changing the boostrap practice.

Comment: @isherwood I actually did that (jsfiddle), but since the only content were the three dots, I failed to notice the issue right away. **guilt92** - If I understand you correctly, you want something like a crossfade animation? Fading out of one tab's content overlapping with the fading in of the other tab's content?

Comment: @FiddlingAway: Yes, that's it, but i'd like not to do a full custom dev: only to change the way the boostrap tab function works: instead of "hiding" the active tab and fade in the new tab, i would like it to "fade out" the active tab before and fade in the new tab. If necessary, i can modify the boostrap.min.js as it's a small project which won't need maintenance overtime. However, i tried to edit it but could find the lines where it hides the tab... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this. The notes are below the example.

The example itself was posted like this (instead of breaking it into appropriate parts in the snippet editor) because there were issues in getting it to work as it does now. I suspect it has something to do with the way the external files are loaded on SO.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .tab-content {
                position: relative;
            }
            .tab-content > .tab-pane {
                display: unset;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 2s;
            }
            .tab-content > .tab-pane.active {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .tab-pane > div {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                margin: 15px;
            }
            .red {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .blue {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .yellow {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            .purple {
                background-color: purple;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link" id="pills-disabled-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-disabled" aria-selected="false" disabled>Disabled</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">
                <div class="red">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer ...</div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">
                <div class="blue">... took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining ...</div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab" tabindex="0">
                <div class="yellow">... essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing...</div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-disabled" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-disabled-tab" tabindex="0">
                <div class="purple">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            const pills = document.querySelectorAll("button.nav-link");
            const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-pane");

            for(var i = 0; i < pills.length; i++) {
                pills[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                    let contentId = event.target.getAttribute("id").replaceAll("-tab","");
                    let elemTab = document.getElementById(contentId);

                    for(var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
                        tabs[j].classList.remove("active");
                    }

                    if(elemTab) {
                        elemTab.classList.add("active");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some caveats / YMMV / general notes:

- the `data-bs-target` inside the pills / menu buttons, has been emptied, to prevent default Bootstrap behaviour. This might lead to some problems later on, if you rely on the behaviour which no longer works as it once did by default
- the positioning of all `.tab-pane` items has been set to `absolute`, to achieve the overlapping. Again, this might not work for you and your specific use-case, especially if you have additional content below your tabs (footers, sliders, blocks of text, etc). In that case, you would have to place your tabbed content inside a container, and perhaps define a fixed height (with overflow and optional changes for different resolutions)
- instead of the default way Bootstrap handles this (see CSS rules / source for `.fade:not(.show)` and `.tab-content > .tab-pane` in the initial Bootstrap setup), this solution / suggestion applies changes in opacity
- of the additional CSS, the things that matter in your case are the first three CSS rules. Namely:

```
.tab-content {
    position: relative;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
    display: unset;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works very well, even if it's quite an important change. I wish there were a simpler way but i'll adapt thanks to your code.